# How do I keep text in place and responsive with different screensizes

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5

I am trying to get my text to stay in place (responsive) with the image size. Is this possible? If so how do I do it, I can't really find much about it.

I am very new to web development in general so any help would be grand. As I've said, I googled everywhere and I can't find anything about it all!

Thanks so much in advance guys!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>South Yorkshire RPC</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!--Font Awesome-->
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/b5212ab333.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    <!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-A3rJD856KowSb7dwlZdYEkO39Gagi7vIsF0jrRAoQmDKKtQBHUuLZ9AsSv4jD4Xa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <style type="text/css">

      #logo-space{
        display:block;
        margin: 0 auto;
        height: auto;
        width: auto;
        background-color: #0f2471;
      }

      #jumbotron{
          margin-top: -50px;
          background-image: url("img/img-1.png");
      }

      #fms-button{
        float: right; 
        position: relative; 
        top: 2rem; 
        right: 5rem;
        background-color: #030b29;
        color: white;

        width: 10rem;
        height: auto;
        
      }

      #logo-space img{
        width: 20rem;
        padding: 5px;
        position: relative;
        left: 45px;
      }

      #about-us{
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        background-color: red;

        bottom: 18rem;

      }

      #about-us h1{
        font: bold;
        font-size: 2rem;
        color: white;
      }

      .nav-bar{
          background-color: #16377e;
          position: relative;
      }

      .navbar-element-left{
        position: relative;
        left: 50px;
        font-weight: bold;
        padding-right: 15px;
      }

      .navbar-element-right{
        position: relative;
        right: 50px;
        font-weight: bold;
        padding-left: 15px;
      }

      #second-section{
        position: relative;
        background-image: url("img/l3.png");
        background-color: red;
        margin-top: -150px;
        width: 618;
        height: 1920;
      }

      .carousel-item {
          width: auto;
          height: auto;
      }
      
      .center{
        text-align: center;
        margin: auto;
      }

      .bigger{
        width:100%;
        height:500px;
        background-image:url('img/l3.png');
        background-size:cover;
        background-position:center;
        position:relative;
        bottom: 5rem;
      }

      .about-header{
        width:auto;
        height:auto;
        background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
        position:absolute;
        bottom: 15rem;
        left: 15rem;
        text-align:center;
        color:white;
      }

      .about-text{
        width: auto;
        height:auto;
        background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
        position:absolute;
        bottom: 15rem;
        left: 55rem;
        text-align:center;
        color:white;

        inline-size: 15rem;
        overflow-wrap: break-word;
      }

    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="logo-space">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="img/logo.png"></a>
    </div>

    <div id="home">
      <nav id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg nav-bar">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active text-white navbar-element-left" aria-current="page" href="#home">HOME</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link text-white navbar-element-left" href="#about">ABOUT US</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link text-white navbar-element-left" href="#divisions">DIVISIONS</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link text-white navbar-element-left" href="#appeals">APPEALS</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link text-white navbar-element-left" href="#feed">FEED</a>
              </li>

              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link text-white navbar-element-left" href="#application">APPLY NOW</a>
              </li>

              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link text-white navbar-element-left" href="--">Head to FMS</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>

    <div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <img src="img/img-1.png" class="d-block w-100 img-fluid" alt="...">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img src="img/img-2.png" class="d-block w-100 img-fluid" alt="...">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img src="img/img-3.png" class="d-block w-100 img-fluid" alt="...">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="bigger">
      <div class="about-header"><h1>Who are we?</h1></div>
      <div class="about-text" style="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore, ea nihil qui atque nulla architecto? Non alias reiciendis in aliquam!</div>
    </div>

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I need more information. What text are you trying to put with the images? What happens when you resize it? The more detail the better.

Comment: Hey yes, this is how i want it to look at all times:
https://gyazo.com/786f2bf19f7987f756f89da18997065e

But when, I make my monitor size smaller it does this:

https://gyazo.com/19931ffe07235b6c0047279582ac2f01

I am hoping to keep it all the same size

Comment: Try using percentages `%`